# Login form is not working with Safari

Tags: forms, authentication, safari

I need some help with my login form. On every browser I am able to login except Safari 8.

```
<form action="index.php?mod=users&do=login" name="frm" id="frm" class="rf" method="post">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="<?php Outtext($frmdata['email']); ?>" class="rfield"><br>
    <div class="verror"><?php if($error['email']!='') Outtext($error['email']); ?></div>
    <br>
    <label for="password">Passwort</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="" class="rfield"><br>
    <div class="verror"><?php if($error['password']!='') Outtext($error['password']); ?></div>
    <br>
    <button name="login" class="login-button button">Login</button><br>
    <a href="index.php?mod=users&do=forgot_password"><span style="color:#030303">Passwort</span> vergessen?</a>
    <a class="registerButton" href="#">Registrieren?</a>
    <a class="manager_loginButton" href="#"><span style="color:#030303">Studiomanager</span> Login</a>
    <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="<?php echo($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">
</form>
```

Comment: As far as I recall, Safari injects HTML into the page for password/username fields. Do a diff between your expected HTML output, the output from (say) chrome, and then Safari. if there's any differences - note them here.

Comment: this one worked for me
<input type="hidden" name="login" value="login">

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="login" value="login">
```

Right under the other

```
<input type=hidden>
```

tag.